# How to convert Speech to text using google api

Tags: python, nlp, speech-recognition, speech-to-text, google-speech-api

what solution will you suggest
I want to Convert speech to text, not in English and then translate text to English look for specific keywords save data in the database
[image]

Comment: Are you asking for suggestion or just want to know the usage of GCP API? I suggest you to check Google Cloud document first.

Comment: @James yes I am exploring GCP Documentation, need suggestion if someone already is done with the same requirement as a mentioned in architecture

Comment: can you explain more on this usecase? what language/s are you targeting? what keywords are stored in database? how are you maintaining the db? etc

Comment: Hey, @RC0993 am using it for Udru 'ur-Pk' i want to extract data from the conversation e.g name, age. will you give me a favor to discuss with me what architecture/flow you used for your application

Comment: Hey, @syedirfan Are you trying to detect speech from a streaming input or from an audio file? If in both cases you need to change the language code to "ur-PK" if it is listed in the list of supported languages (which I think it is). Then you need to pass the urdu font string to the translation API [(here is the documentation)](https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/reference/rest/v2/translate). Then You might want to develop your algorithm to search for the names (Proper Nouns). I am not sure if there is any service which can understand names on its own

Comment: Hi @syedirfan As my initial understanding, I think you are getting the streaming response from Google. Let's say at a time stamp `t` you get the response from Google as **"was with rohan and"**, here _"rohan"_ is a name and you want to take this name and add in some database. Is that correct?

Comment: @RC0993 Correct

Comment: If you **already know** which names are going to appear in the transcript then you might use Levenshtein algorithm to match the names (in case you expect any misspells and other things). If you do not know which names are gonna come then my first guess is going to be ML programming and  you would need to train a Neural Network to properly fetch the names for you.

Comment: Ok, Thanks  @RC0993 T